# php extract() function

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to implement an extract function to grab data from my database and display it in a form so i cn update the database. the form is ok but the extract function..
this is what i have:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$qP = "SELECT * FROM test_mysql WHERE id = '$id'  ";
$rsP = mysql_query($qP);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($rsP);
extract($row);
$fullname = trim($fullname);
$dob = trim($dob);
$time = trim($time);
```

but its telling me:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects
>   parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given

and

> Warning: extract() expects parameter
>   1 to be array, null given

thing is the code is working fine in ConTEXT but giving that error in dremweaver. 
what could be the problem?

Comment: Please,please,please make sure to add some sanitisation to your $id variable with `mysql_real_escape_string`- remember "Little Bobby Tables" http://xkcd.com/327/ :)

Comment: seengee, +1. Or use intval() if a number is expected. Or change to prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

You most probably have an error with MySQL. Try this:

```
$rsP = mysql_query($qP) or die(mysql_error());
```

This will tell you if something goes wrong with your query.

Some possible errors I can think of right away that you should investigate:

- Do you have a connection to the database (using mysql_connect)?
- Do the table test_mysql exist?
- Is $_GET['id'] a number or a string? If it is a number, the end of your query should be changed to `id = $id`

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to a return value of false from the database (or lack thereof).

Answer (score 0):

As specified in PHP manual,

> mysql_query() returns a resource on
>   success, or FALSE on error.

So, looks like there's problem in query. You may look at error message and continue problem investigation:

```
$qP = "SELECT * FROM test_mysql WHERE id = '$id'  ";
$rsP = mysql_query($qP);
echo mysql_error();
```

Answer (score -2):

I encountered the same problem.. and I fixed it by simply doing this...

In your codes where you have

```
extract($row);
```

Change it to

```
 extract((array)$row);
```

Hope it helps.. thank you... it only shows that the variable in `$row` in there is an array and not just a single variable.

Comment: His problem is not the extract is the query. Enforcing array does not make the code work just makes sure the second error about the extract does not pop.